# Targeting Tab error

Tags: web8

we are getting below error when click on Targeting tab.

The ResolveEntitySet function must return a non-null Uri for the EntitySet 'Mappings', otherwise you must set the BaseUri property.
[image]
The ResolveEntitySet function must return a non-null Uri for the EntitySet 'Mappings', otherwise you must set the BaseUri property.

```
at Microsoft.OData.Client.UriResolver.GetEntitySetUri(String entitySetName)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.UriWriter.VisitQueryableResourceExpression(QueryableResourceExpression rse)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.UriWriter.Translate(DataServiceContext context, Boolean addTrailingParens, Expression e, Uri& uri, Version& version)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQueryProvider.Translate(Expression e)
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.Execute()
   at Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceQuery`1.GetEnumerator()
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Models.SmartTarget.Topology.TopologyHelper.GetInstances()
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Models.SmartTarget.SmartTargetInstances.GetListSmartTargetInstances()
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Models.SmartTarget.Services.GetListSmartTargetInstances()
   at SyncInvokeGetListSmartTargetInstances(Object , Object[] , Object[] )
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.SyncMethodInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at Tridion.Web.UI.Core.Extensibility.DataExtenderOperationInvoker.Invoke(Object instance, Object[] inputs, Object[]& outputs)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc& rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
```

Target Tab details
[image]

we are getting below error
[image]
Can you please help me how to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Ramesh

Comment: Is your Topology Manager working? How about the Discovery Service on all of the environments registered as online in that Topology Manager?

Comment: Thanks for quick response, However we are not using Topology Manager in our environment.

Comment: You may not be using it, but you have it installed and XO might be talking to it. So it's worth checking if there are errors with it.

Comment: Speaking of not using the TTM, have you set up XO to use the legacy publishing model then? http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-0A3CAF9E-E11D-4569-94FE-E4730310D7DE

Comment: Yes, we have configured Target tab. Please see edited question.

Comment: You are pointing to the Management service there. The management service requires the Topology Manager and other standalone services. If you are just upgrading and want to keep it the old legacy way, you should enter the URL to your old OData service where you have also installed the new XO in-process files. You cannot mix and match scenarios here -- you either do the simple, temporary upgrade (everything in-process, no standalone services) or you install the new services and Topology Manager.

Answer (score 1):

You are pointing to the Management service in your Target Type, but you do not have that installed and configured correctly. The management service requires the Topology Manager and other standalone services.

If you are just upgrading and want to keep it the old legacy way, you should enter the URL to your old OData service where you have also installed the new XO in-process files.

You cannot mix and match scenarios here -- you either do the simple, temporary upgrade (everything in-process, no standalone services) or you install the new services and Topology Manager.

Answer (score 0):

1. Have you configured the SmartTargetManagementCapability in the Discovery service?

   2. Check whether you have specified the OAuth settings correctly in it?
   3. Check the log files for your Discovery and XO Management Microservices

Hope this helps to troubleshoot the issue